# Type of Person Entries and Group Entries

Tags: iphone

In iphone, what are the type of Person entries and Group Entries?

1) ABPersonRef and ABGroupRef
2) ABPerson and ABGroup
3) ABRecordRef and ABRecordRef
4) ABRecord and ABRecord
5) None of Above

please anybody tell me which option is write one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Address Book database, information is stored in records, represented by ABRecordRef objects. Each record represents a person or group.

Person records are made up of both single-value and multivalue properties. Properties that a person can have only one of, such as first name and last name, are stored as single-value properties. Other properties that a person can have more that one of, such as street address and phone number, are multivalue properties.

Users may organize their contacts into groups for a variety of reasons. For example, a user may create a group containing coworkers involved in a project, or members of a sports team they play on. Your application can use groups to allow the user to perform an action for several contacts in their address book at the same time.

Group records have only one property, kABGroupNameProperty, which is the name of the group. To get all the people in a group, use the function ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers

For More Information, visit [Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html)